# How is highp float presented in GLSL?

Tags: c, floating-point, glsl, shader

Refer to [opengles_shading_language](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) section 4.5:

> It is strongly advised that the vertex language provide a floating point range and precision matching that
>   of an IEEE single precision floating point number, or better. It is required that the vertex language
>   provide floating point variables whose range is at least (-262, 262) and whose precision is at least one part
>   in 65536. This is stated in more detail in the following tables

If assumed that it is an [IEEE single precision floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), how is the relative precision is only 2^-16 with 23bit fraction?

Answer (score 2):

The text you've quoted says:

- Range at least (-262, 262) with precision at least 2^-16 is **required**
- Full IEEE single-precision float is **strongly advised**

So *if* the vertex language provides the IEEE single-precision float, it will indeed have better resolution than 2^-16. However, that is not *required.*

Comment: Got it! So n bit fraction means (1/2^n) relative precision? So 1 bit sign + 7 bits exponent + 16 bits  = 24 bits at least for highp, 1+5+10=16 bits at least for mediump, 1+1+8 = 10 bits at least for lowp?